# Beaglebone Black LCD/TFT/display and I2C2

Tags: i2c, lcd, beaglebone-black, tft, glcd

I am considering buying a 4D Systems I2C LCD for the BBB, e.g. a [7" touchscreen](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12086), which uses the I2C2 bus.

The question is, will I be able to use other peripherals on I2C2, on a home made cape, alongside the LCD ?

Comment: A quick read of the datasheet from your link may have the answers you need. Start at section 3.7 and refer to the schematic.

Comment: Whether the LCD uses the I2C bus does not tell if in practice, it allows enough bandwidth for a user application. Can you find this information in the datasheet ?

Answer (score 1):

Ask 4D, or the 4D forum.

However, it looks to me that the I2C bus is used only for an on-board EEProm interface.  Probably to store/read setup and user data.  I would *guess* that there's plenty of bandwidth left over on the bus for you to use.

Do be aware that this board has the pull-ups already installed for this bus, so be careful about adding more pull-ups elsewhere.  See the "ID EEPROM" section of the schematic in the datasheet, Page 8.

Answer (score -1):

What about this one? It's from Newhaven Display and it's more inexpensive than the one you're looking at.
http://www.mouser.com/new/newhavendisplay/newhaven-beaglebone-cape/